# string manipulation python for removing tags (webscraping)

Tags: python, string

```
n =  '\n            \n                \n                \n                    £10.00 (14%)\n                \n            \n            \n        '
for ietms in n:
    n2 = n.replace('\n', '')
    n3 = n2.replace(' ', '')
    n4 = n3.split('(')
    n5 = n4[1].replace(')', '')

f = [n4[0], n5]
print(f)
```

so i currently have this to remove the \n tags and spaces from the the n variable but i feel as if there is a way to do this in a better optimied manner and was wondering if anyone could help,
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python str has a method called [strip()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/string_strip.htm) which removes whitespace characters and special characters like \n and \r before and after text.

So you could simplify your program to be:

```py
n =  '\n            \n                \n                \n                    £10.00 (14%)\n                \n            \n            \n        '
print(n.strip())
```

Which would then output: `'£10.00 (14%)'`

Comment: what do you mean by tag?

Comment: \n is recognized as a white space character and is therefore removed before and after the data.